# Spaces in SETX PATH command

Tags: windows-server-2003, batch-file, environment-variables

Suppose my PATH is `C:\WINDOWS\system32\;C:\Program Files\Important\`

```
SET NEW_PATH=C:\My\Dir\
SETX PATH "%PATH%;%NEW_PATH%"
```

Results in a path of:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\;C:\Program Files\Important\;C:\My\Dir"
```

Notice the quotation mark at the end of the path.  It's as though the backslash at the end of %NEW_PATH% escaped the final quote mark.  I need the quotation marks because I have spaces in my path, but I don't want backslashes to be interpreted as escape characters.

What's the right way to include my PATH in the call to SETX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't put a backslash at the end of `%NEW_PATH%`.

If you got random input to begin with instead of stuff you control, then you can do one of the following:

- Leave out the closing quotation mark. This does work in some cases:

  ```
  > setx foo "bar baz

  > echo %foo%
  bar baz
  ```

  But doesn't do so well in others:

  ```
  > setx foo "Some stuff "with" embeddded quotes

  > echo %foo%
  Some stuff with embeddded quotes
  ```

  However, you have that problem already to begin with, so what you did there was dangerous at best, since it would destroy quoted paths [(which you need if your path includes a semicolon)](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/29/776926.aspx).

  Which leads us to the following option:
- Properly escape whatever goes into the command:

  ```
  set NEW_PATH=C:\I\Hate\User\Dirs\In\The\Root\
  rem Note the extra quotation marks; we're constructing the complete
  rem argument to setx here.
  set NEW_PATH_VAR="%PATH%;%NEW_PATH%"
  rem The great escape
  set NEW_PATH_VAR=%NEW_PATH_VAR:"=\"%
  setx PATH %NEW_PATH_VAR%
  ```

Comment: That's great! (in an awful soul-sucking kind of way - I hate Windows batch-file programming).  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If `NEW_PATH` does not contain spaces, then you do not need to quote it:

```vb
SET NEW_PATH=C:\My\Dir\
SETX PATH "%PATH%";%NEW_PATH%
```

If `NEW_PATH` does contain spaces, you could use the literal value, and again
not quote the final backslash:

```vb
SETX PATH "%PATH%;C:\My Dir"\
```